# Migrating VSTS\TFVC code to Git DevOps on different domain

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, devops

About 4-5 years ago, we made a free VSTS\TFVC account at visualstudio.com if i remember correctly.

We used our private email like hotmail to make the account. It was free for 5 users.

Recently microsfot did some renaming\rebradning, and called it now DevOps, not sure how all the terms work.

The problem is, now our company has its own DevOps which is somehow connected to the orginazitions sharepont\teams\etc.

We would now like to migrate our VSTS\TFVC code from the old account to our DevOps account which is connected to our orignization. We would like to transfer the VSTS\TFVC code to Git.

Is this possible?, we would ofcourse like to keep all the commits, comments, history, etc..

Comment: Hi, how are things going? Can you use git-tfs to migrate the history successfully?

Comment: Sorry, still havnt tested it out. Was on vacation. Gonna try this out next week.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can.

First you need to create the PAT token of the old org, and go your company org, open the project you want to clone to. Open repos **Files**, choose **Import Repository**.

[image]

Input the code URL of your old org into the **Clone URL**, and **enable** the checkbox-**Requires authorization**. You must authorized it and input the PAT token you create just now into the Password/PAT blank, or you will get the error that **Clone URL requires authorization**.

[image]

Click Import and wait for some seconds until it succeed. It can clone the message with branches, commits, tags and etc.

**Edit:**

Since the old repos type is TFVC, so just choose source type as **TFVC**. Enable migrate history and choose the time scope of history because you want retain the record.

But, as you said in the comment, the longest time you can choose is 180 days. This is **as designed** by Microsoft. You can check this in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-tfvc?view=azure-devops).

And also, the other UI limit is **the imported repository and associated history (if imported) cannot exceed 1GB in size.**

**Edit 2nd**:

Until now, we could not get and migrate all of the history of TFVC repos from UI page. But you can use another tool to achieve what you want : [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md) .

(1) Use git-tfs to **create a locally git repos** from your complete history of TFVC repos .
(2) Push this locally git repos to your remote project.

I check out this doc which can for you refer to achieve what you want: [Advanced migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git#advanced-migrations).

Comment: Yes, but my old solution is on a VSTS source, not GIT. Or maybe its TFVC. Im not really sure. What i am sure about is that it is not GIT

Comment: Doesn't the source file type of old account is not GIT? If it's git, you can import them.

Comment: Merlin Liang: thats the problem. The old source is TFVC i think, not Git. So it needs to be converted somehow to Git as well.

Comment: oki, i think i got something. I was able to convert from TFVC to Git in the old server, which kind of worked, but i only got 180days of histoy. After this i went through your procedure, and it worked Now i have to figure out how to get the whole history.

Comment: @Mana, I have modify my answer with your condition. Until now, Microsoft could not provide the feature to move all of history.

Comment: it would be awesome to have the whole history, do you know of any other way ? thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: @Mana Check my second updated, I found a doc that you can use another tool to achieve whole history of TFVC repos. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks, i think this might work. i'll let you know.